# Java - API for joining Lists with SQL syntax

Tags: java, sql, list, api, join

I would like to know if there's a Java API for joining lists and generate a new List :

ex:

```
List<Type1> list1 = new ArrayList<>(); // fill it...
List<Type2> list2 = new ArrayList<>(); // fill it...
List<Type3> list3 = new ArrayList<>(); // fill it...

// InMemorySQL#load(Class<T>, List<?>...)
List<Type4> list4 = InMemorySQL.load(Type4.class, list1, list2, list3)
    .executeQuery(
        "SELECT t1.attr1, t2.attr3, t3.attr5"
        + " FROM $1 t1"
        + " LEFT JOIN $2 t2"
        + " ON t1.attr1 = t2.attr2"
        + " LEFT JOIN $3 t3"
        + " ON t2.attr2 = t3.attr2"           
    );
```

Note1 : "$X" (or its alias tX) represents our listX object (in order from parameters), and "$X." calls object's getter OR use attribute's name OR use attribute's annotation which contains a name.

Note2 : Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4 are not from the same family (no inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this kind of API before in Java (maybe LINQ in C# ?), so I have decided to create my own Java API for manipulating Java beans with SQL queries ([see dbms-replication here in github](https://github.com/eau-de-la-seine/dbms-replication)).

See how it works:

```
import fr.ekinci.dbmsreplication.inmemorysql.InMemorySQL;
//...

String sqlRequest = "SELECT t1.id_d1, t1.attr2, t1.attr3, t2.id_d2, t2.attr4, t3.id_d3, t3.attr5 " +
    " FROM t1" +
    " LEFT JOIN t2" +
    " ON t1.id_d1 = t2.id_d1" +
    " LEFT JOIN t3" +
    " ON t2.id_d2 = t3.id_d3" +
    " ORDER BY t1.id_d1, t2.id_d2, t3.id_d3";

List<Dumb1> ldb1 = new ArrayList<>(); // fill it
List<Dumb2> ldb2 = new ArrayList<>(); // fill it
List<Dumb3> ldb3 = new ArrayList<>(); // fill it

Collection<ReturnDumb> result = new InMemorySQL()
    .add(Dumb1.class, ldb1) // ldb1 alias will be t1
    .add(Dumb2.class, ldb2) // ldb2 alias will be t2
    .add(Dumb3.class, ldb3) // ldb3 alias will be t3
    .executeQuery(ReturnDumb.class, sqlRequest);
```

It's still in beta, [see more information on Github (README.md)](https://github.com/eau-de-la-seine/dbms-replication).